# how to set dismissing alert to show just once

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux, reactstrap

I try to find the way to show dismissing alert at the first time when user get in the page, then when user click in that page again it would not show that alert anymore.

I use the code from this website : https://reactstrap.github.io/components/alerts/

my code:

```
    this.state = {

     hasVisitedPageBefore: false,
};

  visitPage() {
this.setState({ hasVisitedPageBefore: true });

 }

showAlert() {
return (
  <Alert color="info" isOpen={this.state.visible} toggle={this.onDismiss}>
    Congratulations! You have been created deck.
  </Alert>
);
  }


 render
{this.state.hasVisitedPageBefore ? null : showAlert}
```

Do you guys know how to check it? Please suggest me.

Thank you

Comment: You can add some sort of identifier, class for example, to reflect that this alert should not be shown and remove it when you want to show it again in the future.

Comment: @ShaharGalukman I try to set state for the alert but it's still not work. when I click in that page the alert still appear

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: What do you mean by "click in that page again"? When you do want the alert to disappear?

Comment: @anand I meant I want to show alert to describe how to use this function at the first time that user get in to use. For the second time, the user just get in to edit so I don't want it appear alert in second time.

Comment: By second time, do you mean "close the browser window, go to sleep, come back a second time next day morning"? Or "go to sub-page and come back to main page"? :)

Comment: @anand go to another page then back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take help of [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to persist flags between different pages

Eg. 
Start in construcor

```
constructor() {
 this.state = {
    hasVisitedPageBefore: localStorage.get("hasVisited") || false,
 };
}
```

Now set the visited flag in

```
visitPage() {
    localStorage.set("hasVisited", true)
    this.setState({ hasVisitedPageBefore: true });
 }
```

You can use [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.sessionStorage) if you want to persist this preference for the current browsing session.

[This is just an idea, Please pardon my syntax]

Comment: while this will solve the problem, it looks like at this point it is more important that @pppp understands how to use react state correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to "remember" that a user has visited a certain page so that when the user visits again, you have to show your page in a different way (i.e. without the alert).

You need to have a state variable `hasVisitedPageBefore` (or whatever you choose to call it!). Set it to have a default value `false` when you start the app. When the page is visited, set the variable to `true`.

Then in your page, show or hide the alert based on whether `hasVisitedPageBefore` is `true` or `false`.

```
    <div>
      {hasVisitedPageBefore?null:<Alert>Message</Alert>}
      <MyPage />
    </div>
```

Feel free to ask if you have trouble figuring out the details.

Comment: still not work, when I back to the page it's till appear.

Comment: Where are you storing your state? If you are storing it on the same page, it will be destroyed when you go away and will have the default value when you come back. Show some of your code, and someone may be able to help.

Comment: Saw your code. You are storing the state in the same component as your page. It will be lost when you go to a different page. Store the state it in a parent component and pass it down to your page as `prop`.

Comment: Glad to be of help. Cheers!! :)